# Nachdenken, Überlegen, Bedenken

Tags: meaning

Könnte jemand bitte erklären, was genau der Unterschied zwischen den Verben "nachdenken", "überlegen" und "bedenken" ist?

Danke!

Comment: Was hast Du mit einem Wörterbuch herausgefunden? Wo sind die Unklarheiten genau?

Comment: Das ist eine gute Frage, aber man sollte wirklich zeigen, dass er selber schon versucht hat, die Frage zu beantworten. Was sind denn deine Definitionen, und was sind die Quellen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bedenken=

1)Etwas abwägen (reagierend zB Vorteile vs Nachteile abwägen) und/oder       warnend. In manchen Zusammenhängen etwas veraltet aber auch teilweise eine gehobene Ausdrucksweise.
  "Bedenken Sie einmal die Folgen"

2)Jemandem etwas zuwenden. (zB im Testament bedenken)
  "Max hat Moritz mit 10.000€ bedacht"

überlegen= eher weiter gefasst

1) Kreative Beschäftigung mit einem Problem, also zB eine Lösung suchen 
   "Ich muss mir da eine Lösung überlegen"

2) Etwas abwägen (reagierend zB Vorteile vs Nachteile abwägen)
   "Das muss ich mir noch überlegen"

nachdenken= weniger konkret

1) wie überlegen

2) "Philosophisches Denken"
   "Er denkt über die Zukunft nach"

3) Selbstkritisches Denken (zB über Handlungen oder Verhalten)
   "Über dein Verhalten in der Schule solltest du gut nachdenken"

Diese Wörter stehen aber nur teilweise in Konkurrenz und können oft synonym verwendet werden, einzig "bedenken" ist relativ eng zu verstehen, "nachdenken" wohl das weiteste Wort.

Comment: Gute Antwort... Quellen?